# Selenium Firefox Pop-up blocker leads to fail the test case execution

Tags: asp.net, firefox, selenium, c#-4.0, tridion-2011

We are using the selenium with firefox webdriver to automate all our test cases.
 I'm automating the SDL Tridion manual activities like Creating a Component, Creating a Page, Tridion out-of box search etc....
When I run the test cases for Page Creation test case, **Firefox's pop up blocker ending up blocking the window that is supposed to open. This leads to failing the test case,** but for other test cases it is working fine(FYI : I'm running it from my local)
On the top of this selenium project we have built one asp.net web application and the application has been configured in the IIS Successfully. When I run this project by hitting the server URL, All the test cases got executed successfully.(Note: No Firefox pop-up blocker issue)
But we couln't execute the selenium project from our local, because of the firefox driver pop-up blocker issue.
I have tried a couple of things but they didn't work out, And those are mentioned here
**1. Given the URL of the site in the firefox setting's(Options->Content->Add Exceptions->URL of the Site)**
**2. Setting the preference in the firefox profile like below**

```
[TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
            try
            {
                //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                //FirefoxBinary fb = new FirefoxBinary(@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FirefoxBinaryLocation"]);
                FirefoxBinary fb = new FirefoxBinary(@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FirefoxBinaryLocation"]);
                FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
                fp.SetPreference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore");

                driver = new FirefoxDriver(fb, fp);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                logger.WriteError("Exception in instantiating Firefox driver : " + ex.Message);                
            }
        }
```

Firefox Version :- 38.5.2
Webdriver Version :- 2.48.0.0
Any help would be greatly appreciated..Thanks...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Popups are handled in Firefox with the key "dom.disable_open_during_load". You can set this key value to false, which will allow popup windows. This key value can be set in desired capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my post. Actually I was using `element.sendKeys(Enter)`, Actually this won't work out while clicking a button in firefox. So I changed this to JavaScript Executor, I added the below code and it is working fine

```
IwebElement element = driver.findelement(By.Id("Id name goes here"))
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();",element);
```

Hope this might helpful to others.